# Validating python dependencies

Tags: python, pip

I am taking a list of python dependencies to install on a docker image from the user, is there a way I can use pip or internals of pip to check the requirements.txt (dependencies) are correctly specified ?

I found this https://github.com/doismellburning/pep508, but this requires me to install parsley, I was hoping pip would have some implementation for this.

Comment: I definitely wouldn't recommend depending on Parsley in new code; it was last updated in 2015.

Comment: @data-cyclist if I answered your question, please mark it as accepted. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the `--dry-run` flag.

```
pip install -r .\requirements.txt --dry-run
```

[doc for --dry-run](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-dry-run)